# How to get Firefly out of an exchange that has suspended withdrawals

Tags: firefly

I have a problem that I don't think 9s unique. I own some $IOTA coins on gate.io exchange. In fact, I recently bought more coins when I heard about the 90-day IOTA/Shimmer staking project. So, I downloaded Firefly, created a wallet, and scanned the QR code, intending to send my $IOTA from gate.io to Firefly.

But gate.io has suspended withdrawal of $IOTA, with no explanation and no date for reinstatement. So, my question is this... How can I get my $IOTA coins into Firefly?

Is there some way I could swap them for another coin on gate (maybe XLM?), send that coin to Firefly, and then swap them for IOTA inside Firefly? I'm not even worried about losing a few percent in the trade - I just want IOTA in Firefly before the 90-day staking project starts.

Any ideas would be gratefully appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. Can't withdrawal Iota. What joke from Gate.io

Comment: Read somewhere this is an issue with IOTA network. If their ecosystem can't hold transactions - this is a big red flag- not worth investing

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am trying for the first time on 28 Nov 2021 to move IOTA off of gate.io over to firefly and It wont let me.[![screenshot from gate.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbaUN.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbaUN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Update, I used Bitfinex (if you are in usa, you will need to use a VPN) to get IOTA then transfer over to the Firefly wallet. I just sold off my IOTA on the gate platform since they could not fix the "maintenance" issue.

Answer (score 1):

Huobi is open for withdrawl now.

Same as most other big exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with gate.io, but I would assume that they did not update their withdrawal logic for the changes in the [Chrysalis update](https://blog.iota.org/the-chrysalis-token-migration-starts-now/) in April 2021.

Firefly does not support other tokens, so your best way is to pick another exchange which supports Chrysalis (see the article linked above for a list, or check other sources and verify with them that they did the update) and send your funds converted to another cryptocurrency (be it XRP or BCH or whatever common currency is there that does not take horrendous withdrawal fees) to the other exchange, swap them for IOTA and withdraw them to your Firefly wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i try with Houbi, Hitbtc, gate, brittrex and only binance open the withdrawals. I bought some iota in Houbi, now i wait to the price raice a little more to sell. So, with the btc i think buy XRP (fee 0.5 xrp) to send the coin to Binance and buy iota again ...and finish with the withdrawal to Firefly....uufffff!